# Recorder.js works fine in localhost but not working on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recorder.js

im trying to capture voice from user in my asp.net web application . im using Recorder.js , it looks fine on my localhost but when i upload it to my windows server it dosent ask for permission and it dosent work ! i tired uploading the demo version on my server !
the console shows this error :

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined
> >     at HTMLButtonElement.startRecording (app.js:44)

Comment: not using ssl?.

Comment: no i'm not using SSL , is there a way that I use it without SSL if SSL is needed?

Comment: you need ssl, check console it will be complaining about secure context, device api's like this, geo/location, usb etc require ssl, unless localhost

Comment: thank you , using a self signed certification solved my problem <3